# Scraping Hub Periodic Script / IOError No such file or directory

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I am trying to run a periodic script and connect it with a json file within my project. I tried this (https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200416-deploying-non-code-files) but this is not working for me, structure imported from scraping hub looks very different. Script is working well until i need to call this file.

The error which I got is :

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory  : 'resources/bmibmi-67d3f1f00f49.json'
```

with this in setup.py :

```
package_data={

        'project': ['resources/*.json']

    },
```

Thanks a lot for your help.